# Get user status for each day from status change history

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I use postgres and have non-trivial query. I have 2 solutions, the problem is that they are not fast.

There is a table `user_status_changes`, which is history of user status changes

```sql
 user_id |         created_at  | from_status | to_status
---------+---------------------+-------------+-----------
       3 | 2016-03-24 04:00:00 | active      | pending
       3 | 2016-03-27 19:59:21 | pending     | banned
       6 | 2016-03-16 10:00:00 | pending     | active
       6 | 2016-03-21 15:00:00 | active      | banned
       6 | 2016-03-25 19:52:46 | banned      | pending
       6 | 2016-03-25 20:53:22 | pending     | canceled
```

`users`

```
id |         created_at
----+----------------------------
  3 | 2016-03-21 19:54:09.831252
  6 | 2016-03-14 13:04:09.134358
```

What I wanna get is a list for each day from `user.created_at` till today of user status for date and user status of the previous day.

Example result (assuming today is 2016-03-27):

```
 user_id   | date        | status_at | previous_status
-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------
         3 | 2016-03-21  |           |
         3 | 2016-03-22  |           |
         3 | 2016-03-23  |           |
         3 | 2016-03-24  | pending   |
         3 | 2016-03-25  | pending   | pending
         3 | 2016-03-26  | pending   | pending
         3 | 2016-03-27  | banned    | pending
         6 | 2016-03-14  |           | 
         6 | 2016-03-15  |           | 
         6 | 2016-03-16  | active    | 
         6 | 2016-03-17  | active    | active
         6 | 2016-03-18  | active    | active
         6 | 2016-03-19  | active    | active
         6 | 2016-03-20  | active    | active
         6 | 2016-03-21  | banned    | active
         6 | 2016-03-22  | banned    | banned
         6 | 2016-03-23  | banned    | banned
         6 | 2016-03-24  | banned    | banned
         6 | 2016-03-25  | canceled  | banned
         6 | 2016-03-26  | canceled  | canceled
         6 | 2016-03-27  | canceled  | canceled
```

I have 2 solutions in mind. One with subqueries (quite slow)

```sql
WITH possible_dates AS (
  SELECT date(generate_series) AS "date"
    FROM generate_series(
      (SELECT min(created_at) FROM users)::date,
      '2016-03-27'::date,
      '1 day'
    )
)
SELECT 
  user_id,
  possible_dates.date,
  (
    SELECT to_status 
    FROM user_status_changes 
    WHERE user_status_changes.user_id = users.user_id
      AND date(user_status_changes.created_at) <= possible_dates.date
    ORDER BY user_status_changes.created_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS status_at,
  LAG(
      SELECT to_status 
      FROM user_status_changes 
      WHERE user_status_changes.user_id = users.user_id
        AND date(user_status_changes.created_at) <= possible_dates.date
      ORDER BY user_status_changes.created_at DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) OVER (PARTITION BY users.user_id ORDER BY possible_dates.date ASC) AS previous_status
FROM users
CROSS JOIN possible_dates
WHERE date(users.created_at) <= possible_dates.date
```

Another via joins (seems to be faster):

```sql
WITH status_changes AS (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT ON(user_id, date)
    user_id,
    created_at::date AS date,
    to_status,
    from_status
  FROM user_status_changes
  ORDER BY user_id, date, created_at DESC
),
possible_dates AS (
  SELECT date(generate_series) AS "date"
        FROM generate_series(
          (SELECT min(created_at) FROM users)::date,
          '2016-03-27'::date,
          '1 day'
        )
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (users.user_id, possible_dates.date)
  users.user_id AS user_id,
  possible_dates.date AS date,
  s1.to_status AS status_at,
  s2.to_status AS previous_status
FROM users
CROSS JOIN possible_dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN status_changes s1
   ON s1.date <= possible_dates.date
  AND s1.user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT
    status_changes.to_status,
    status_changes.date
  FROM status_changes
  WHERE
    status_changes.date < possible_dates.date AND
    status_changes.user_id = users.user_id
) s2 ON true
WHERE date(users.created_at) <= possible_dates.date
ORDER BY users.user_id, possible_dates.date DESC, s1.date DESC, s2.date DESC;
```

Currently we have around 20k users, ~10 payments and 2 status changes per month per user. First user was created 1 year ago.

I believe the issue with joins approach is that we join all previous status changes and remove redundant only afterwards via `DISTINCT ON`.

Any better solutions will be much appreciated, index suggestions are welcome as well.

Comment: I would first try to reduce the size of the table by creating a temporary table that would only contain the last entry of a day for each user (i.e. the end status of a user at any given day). Once you have that, the second query on that table would be trivial. By the way, when you say the response time is slow (your first option) what do you mean? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: Basically I'm doing that in `status_changes` view in the second solution (with joins). Current query takes hours to complete.

Comment: Pretty sophisticated need :-) I've worked quite some time on this, LATERAL seems to be the bottleneck. Hope you'll enjoy it . . .

Answer (score 1):

Never, *Never* use "date(field) >=" and other functions on potentially indexed column. This kills any possibility of using normal (not functional) indexes.

```
select user_id, s_date, status_at,
       lag(status_at) over(partition by user_id order by part,s_date) previous_status
  from
  (
   select user_id, s_date, part,
          first_value(to_status)
          over(partition by user_id,part order by s_date) status_at
     from
     (
       select U.id as user_id, s_date,
              first_value(to_status) over(partition by U.id,s_date order by S.created_at desc) to_status,
              count(to_status) over (partition by U.id order by s_date) as part,
              row_number() over (partition by U.id,s_date order by S.created_at desc) rn
         from users U
         left join
              generate_series(date(U.created_at),'2016-03-27'::date,'1 day') s_date ON true
         left join user_status_changes S
           on S.user_id=U.id
             and S.created_at between s_date and s_date+'23:59:59.999'::interval
     ) D where rn=1
   ) C
```

May be need `create index user_status_dt on user_status_changes(user_id, created_at)`

Comment: Actually, Postgres supports functional indexes, so this doesn't kill the possibility of using it if one already has it :-)

Comment: @KamilG. Then have necessary to build functional indexes for each query. Also on accurate DateTime index allows you to use it on "order by date limit 1"

Comment: I'm not questioning whether or not it's better to create normal rather than functional index. You've stated that it __kills__ the possibility which isn't true.

Comment: What's the purpose of `LATERAL` here?

Comment: @freemanoid What would generate_series could refer to a column in "users". And create individual date sequence for each user

Comment: Also could you please explain why you use `count` here as an unique ID even though it can have duplicates.

Comment: @freemanoid Duplicates are not terrible. "part" should be the same until the "to_status" is NULL and any other when "to_status" present. Strict sequence is not required, only an indication that the status has changed

Comment: Regarding `LATERAL`, I don't see any reference to users table in this lateral join. Also when I remove `LATERAL` keyword I have the same result for this subquery.

Comment: @freemanoid Hmm. I agree. now the truth I do not understand why generate_series seeing U.created_at :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123773/discussion-between-freemanoid-and-mike).

Answer (score 1):

My query doesn't use `LATERAL` which needs to calculate for every row like yours or @Mike's does so this should be much faster.

### Explanation

First generate the data set as you've already been doing. *CTE:* `generate_dates`.

Then limit the output to dates for each user from their creation and get statuses that were set on these dates. *CTE:* `basic_status`.

In the inner select fill the null values between each statuses with a status that was occurring at the moment with `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()` and limit the output throwing out all the statuses set after the date to only the closest using `DISTINCT ON`.

The outer select is just for calculating previous status using `LAG()` window function.

### Query

```
WITH generate_dates AS (
SELECT date(generate_series) AS date
    FROM generate_series(
      (SELECT min(created_at) FROM users)::date,
      '2016-03-27'::date,
      '1 day'
    )
)
, basic_status AS (
SELECT 
  u.id AS user_id, 
  g.date,
  s.to_status AS status_at,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY g.date) AS rownum
FROM users u
JOIN generate_dates g ON
  g.date > u.created_at - interval '1 day'
LEFT JOIN user_status_changes s ON
  u.id = s.user_id
  AND s.created_at BETWEEN g.date AND g.date + interval '1 day'
)
SELECT 
  *,
  LAG(status_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) AS previous_status
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON ( b1.user_id, b1.date )
    b1.user_id,
    b1.date,
    COALESCE(b1.status_at, b2.status_at) AS status_at
  FROM basic_status b1
  LEFT JOIN basic_status b2 ON
    b1.user_id = b2.user_id
    AND b1.status_at IS NULL
    AND b2.status_at IS NOT NULL
    AND b1.rownum > b2.rownum
  ORDER BY b1.user_id, b1.date DESC, b2.rownum DESC
  ) foo;
```

### Index

You could create following indexes to speed it up:

- `users(id)`
- `user_status_changes(user_id, created_at`)
- `users(created_at)` - this one may not be that important

### Notes

Remember to update your statistics for more accurate cost estimation using `ANALYZE table`.

Comment: Estimated cost you query 41541k against 543k in my case. I hope the author of question will compare our versions on a real database

Comment: Indeed, let's wait for the result but you may be right :-) Thanks for your input